# how to subscribe to laser /scan topic and publish a customized scan topic back

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, sensor-msgs, publisher, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to consider any 72 points from the 'scan' topic for my other application. Currently the lidar i am using gives around 2000 points. I want to take only 72 points out of it and publish it as a new topic 'revised_scan'.
I tried with a small script in python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
import sensor_msgs.msg

pub = rospy.Publisher('/revised_scan', LaserScan, queue_size = 10)

rev_scan = LaserScan()
    
def callback(msg):
    #print(len(msg.ranges)) len is 2019 from 0-360
    req_range = rev_scan.msg.ranges[0:72]
    pub.publish(req_range)
    
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('revised_scan', anonymous=True)
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

however, it gives me an error saying

```
[ERROR] [1613466169.831151]: bad callback: <function callback at 0x7f99a8d350>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "rev_scan.py", line 12, in callback
    req_range = rev_scan.msg.ranges[0:72]
AttributeError: 'LaserScan' object has no attribute 'msg'
```

Though i can change directly in the lidars source file to publish two topics(scan & revised_scan) but I want to make this as a standard irrespective of the type of lidar I will use in the future.

I appreciate if someone can help with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371902/how-to-subscribe-to-laser-/scan-topic-and-publish-a-customized-scan-topic-back/) by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2021-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made changes to my code as roberto mentioned and works fine.

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
import sensor_msgs.msg

pub = rospy.Publisher('/revised_scan', LaserScan, queue_size = 10)
scann = LaserScan()

def callback(msg):
    #print(len(msg.ranges)) len is 2019 from 0-360
    current_time = rospy.Time.now()
    scann.header.stamp = current_time
    scann.header.frame_id = 'laser'
    scann.angle_min = -3.1415
    scann.angle_max = 3.1415
    scann.angle_increment = 0.00311202858575
    scann.time_increment = 4.99999987369e-05
    scann.range_min = 0.00999999977648
    scann.range_max = 32.0
    scann.ranges = msg.ranges[0:72]
    scann.intensities = msg.intensities[0:72]
    print(scann)
    pub.publish(scann)
    
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('revised_scan', anonymous=True)
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

---

Originally posted by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) with karma: 100 on 2021-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2021-02-16**:
I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a complete answer, as your code has several problems.

Here is one: When new messages are received, `msg` is the variable name for the message that is passed in.

So:

```
rev_scan.msg.ranges[0:72]
```

should be

```
msg.ranges[0:72]
```

Also, note that you have not initialized the message `req_scan` which you are publishing but you initialized `rev_scan` instead, and also you are assigning the ranges to a different variable namely `req_range`.

[sensor_msgs/LaserScan Message](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)
is a somewhat complicated message type, I recommend that you start by trying to republish a simpler message type like `std_msgs/String` and then move on to more complicated types.

This is a good place to start:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2021-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on 2021-02-16**:
oops! thanks. that was a blunder.
i have enclosed my edited code in the next post.